# Writing onmousemove event javascript a different way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I can write document.onmousemove a different way? Here is the code:

```
   document.onmousemove = something;
```

I can only seem to be able to run one function this way, how can I write it a different way?

Comment: You have `jquery` in your tags, why don't you use that?

Comment: That's not jQuery, that's vanilla Javascript. If you use the jQuery event methods like `$.on()`, you can add multiple handlers.

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html and http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: Answers provided by @Barmar and **false** are both good, but to clarify, you'd just repeat that for each function you want to attach to the event.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you can do it this way:

```
$(document).on("mousemove", something);
$(document).on("mousemove", somethingElse);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', something, false);
```

For compatibility with IE8 and earlier, you can fall back on its `attachEvent` (mind the prefix, and you’ll have to use `window.event` instead of the argument):

```
document.attachEvent('onmousemove', something);
```